# SQLite Syntax Error

Tags: sqlite

I made a sql query, below. I am getting an exception which I have shown as well. Any help is appreciated.

### QUERY:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO CLAIMS (DATE ,TIME , ADDRESS , CITY, 
STATE , POSTAL , PHFNAME ,PHLNAME ,PHEMAIL ,PHPHONE ,AGENCY ,POLICY ,VEHICLENAME,
YEAR ,MAKE ,MODEL ,PLATELICENSE ,LSTATE ,VIN ,DRIVERNAME,DRFNAME ,DRLNAME ,
DRPHONE ,DREMAIL ,DRLICENSE) VALUES("Wednesday, May 4, 2011", 
"10:39:10 PM EDT", "400 Chatham","Pune", "Penn", "45223", "John", 
"Richard","jsmith@newyahoo.com","+1-11111111111", 
"Three Rivers Insurance","(null)", "(null)", "(null)", 
"(null)", "(null)","(null)", "(null)", "(null)","(null)", 
"(null)", "(null)","(null)", "(null)","(null)") WHERE DATE  LIKE 
'Wednesday, May 4,%' AND TIME = '10:39:10 PM EDT'
```

### Error:

```
SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error:


 [ near "WHERE": syntax error ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INSERT OR REPLACE` doesn't support `WHERE` clause, see the[SQLite Insert doc](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). You can use a `WHERE` clause in `UPDATE` statements, see the [SQLite Insert doc](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html)

Can help you if you can let us know what you wanted here ?

Comment: thank u for the quick reply. then what can be used with INSERT OR REPLACE instead of WHERE.

Comment: What i want to do is to update the user entered data based on Date and Time.

Comment: If you are inserting only one row, then INSERT or REPLACE doesn't require any other clause. Remove WHERE clause in the query it should work.

Comment: If you have a UNIQUE constraint on DATE and TIME, then your REPLACE statement would handle the CONFLICT.Assuming you have CONSTRAINT defined, any row which has "Wednesday, May 4, 2011", "10:39:10 PM EDT" will now be updated to the new values which you are trying to insert.

Comment: This should help then `UPDATE CLAIMS SET DATE = "Wednesday, May 4, 2011" AND TIME = "...", AND CITY="..." AND ... WHERE DATE LIKE '..%' AND TIME = "..."`

Comment: thanks again. The data comes from the user entered textfield data. If so how will i update. Please find my code below.UPDATE CLAIMS  SET DATE = '%@" AND TIME = '%@'  AND  ADDRESS = '%@'   AND  CITY = '%@' WHERE DATE  LIKE 
'Wednesday, May 4,%' AND TIME = '10:39:10 PM EDT'

Comment: ok finally figured this out. instead of AND I used a , and it worked.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue for sync table for insert and update at a time and finally i use.
To use the insert or replace statement you need to use the coalesce function that required primary key column to put the where clause.

```
COALESCE((SELECT PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE UNIQUE_COLUMN = 'VALUE'),
(SELECT MAX(PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN)+1 FROM TABLE_NAME))
```

it worked for me e.g

```
INSERT OR  REPLACE INTO TBL_ADDRESSES
(ADDRESS_ID,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,ADDRESS3,ADDRESS_NAME,CITY,DB_ID) 
VALUES (
    COALESCE((SELECT ADDRESS_ID FROM TBL_ADDRESSES WHERE DB_ID = '111'),
        (SELECT MAX(ADDRESS_ID)+1 FROM TBL_ADDRESSES)),
    'IT 27','Pratap DSFSDSDDSDSF','test add ','IT 27','Jaipur','111') ;
```